# How Do I Configure a Static Route for a Gateway on the Same Network?

Tags: networking, routing

I'm trying to configure a router to forward traffic to another router on the same network (so that I don't have to configure static routes on each other machine on the network).

Here's a simplistic diagram of the network.

[image]

**Goal**: I want to be able to contact station_d from station_a (without configuring a static route on station_a).

I attempted to create a static route on inet_gateway, like `192.168.3.0/24 10.0.0.5`. When that is in place, I can contact station_d from inet_gateway. However, I cannot contact station_d from station_a. Attempts to contact station_d get routed out to the Internet.

It appears that inet_gateway doesn't know that it's supposed to route the traffic. The ping I send from station_a has the MAC address of inet_gateway in the ethernet header, but inet_gateway doesn't (appear to) forward the traffic to router_b.

If I configure a static route on station_a (exactly like the one I made on inet_gateway), station_a can contact station_d. I don't want to have to maintain static routes like this on all the stations on the network, though.

Is this kind of thing possible: to have a router "route" traffic through another router on the same network as the originator?

**Additional Information**
Here are the routing tables (IP addresses changed to match diagram and protect the innocent). The Internet traffic goes through 192.168.0.1/24.

(inet_gateway)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
loopback        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     10.0.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
```

(router_b)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.3.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ath0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
```

//Bridged Adapters//: This kind of bridging is the default for the Ubiquiti device I'm using. I didn't attempt to unbridge some of the adapters. I put the device into "router" mode, but it still has the adapters bridged. I'm not certain if I can change that. **I think this is unrelated to the fundamental problem.**

### ICMP Redirection

This seems like what I need to get working. Thank you very much for all the advice.

I cannot get inet_gateway to send the ICMP redirects. I believe the device is configured to send them, but its behavior suggests that it believes that it doesn't know it should be sending the redirects.

Attempting a traceroute to station_d from station_a results in this:

```
> tracert -d 192.168.3.10
Tracing route to 192.168.3.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2     1 ms     7 ms     2 ms  192.168.0.1
  3    15 ms    15 ms    16 ms  10.30.0.1
  4    34 ms    37 ms    22 ms  216.229.64.249
  5    35 ms    32 ms    27 ms  216.229.80.185
  6    25 ms    50 ms    35 ms  10.92.1.38
  7    32 ms    30 ms    28 ms  10.92.1.86
```

I would conclude that inet_gateway (Ubiquiti EdgeMax) does not know if should be sending ICMP redirects.

Comment: You should leave it up to the routers to route the traffic. Routers learn routes in three ways: directly connected, statically configured (doesn't scale), dynamically with routing protocols. You could either statically configure a route to the `192.168.3.0/24` network on the Internet router, or you could run a routing protocol in common between the two routers.

Comment: I _did_ configure a static route to 192.168.0.3/24 on the inet_gateway router. (`192.168.3.0     10.0.0.5    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2`) It didn't route the traffic.

Comment: I don't think router_b (Ubiquiti NanoStation M2) exposes any ability to use dynamic routing protocols. It knows how to route between the two networks, but I don't see anything in it that makes me think I can use RIP or anything.

Comment: Is there a typo in your diagram? station_a, station_d, and router_b have the same ip address listed. How about showing us the corrected ip address configuration on all the hosts and show us the actual routing table for each host.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, router_b has 10.0.0.5 and 192.168.3.1; station_d has 192.168.3.10.

Comment: Your basic idea is correct, the Inet gateway would sent ICMP Redirects if your static route is set. You don't say what that router is, it might have strange firewall rules or kernel modules, shurtcutted NAT chains or all kind of strange stuff prohibiting functioning. If this is Linux, check if it is enabled: ` /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects`. You can also try to sniff, maybe the gateway is sending the redirects but the station is ignoring them.

Comment: OK, station_a and router_b still show as having the ip address 10.0.0.5. They both can't have that ip address. Can you correct that and show us the routing table from each host/router?

Comment: @eckes I used tcpdump to capture all ICMP traffic from station_a and saw it arrive at inet_gateway, but I never saw any ICMP traffic arrive at router_b.

Comment: This isn't correct on router_a: `192.168.1.0     10.0.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2`

Comment: It should be `192.168.3.0     10.0.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2`

Comment: Sorry, translation typo. In real life. I it matches the 192.168 network.

Comment: Sorry for all the typos. Half the reason I asked the question was to find out if such thing was even possible. I guess the other half of the question is, how does one configure this in general? I don't think my real addresses are incorrect. I was assuming that I was making a more fundamental mistake.

Comment: So, `station_a` has a default gateway of `10.0.0.1`, the `inet gateway`, which has a route to `192.168.3.0/24` through `router_b` at `10.0.0.5`, and the traffic is not being correctly routed from `station_a` to `station_d` that has a default gateway of `router_b` at `192.168.3.1`?

Comment: station_d has a default gateway, 192.168.3.1. I never see any traffic pass through 10.0.0.5. I only see traffic arrive at 10.0.0.1 (and never see it leave as if forwarded/routed).

Comment: @mojo inet_gateway will not route packets coming from the internal LAN back to the same interface. It will however answer with a ICMP redirect message back to the sender (station a) telling him a temporary route to the actual gateway (router_b).so when sniffing you can't see the forwarded packages - but the new redirects (if they are actually generated). Maybe ubiquity needs a switch for that (I know that Cisco and Linux has this default on).

Comment: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects` is 1.

Comment: @eckes, I was afraid this might be the designed behavior (not forwarding on same network).

Comment: @mojo your routes look fine, it should generate the redirects. Something else is inhibiting them. Check the firewall chains. Also br0 looks suspicious, is your picture really matching your network? (Bridge?)

Comment: As others have said, this should work. inet_gateway should send an ICMP redirect to the 10.0.0.0/16 clients telling them that they can reach the 192.168.3.0/24 clients via router_b. What is the bridge interface on router_b? What interfaces are bridged?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to add gateways to your diagram

Assuming that station_a has the ip 10.0.0.10/16 with gateway 10.0.0.1/16
and this gateway is connected to Router_b 10.0.0.5/16 with internal 192.168.3.1/24 (so the network is 192.168.3.0/24)

you need to tell the (Inner_gateway) add a static route to 
192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 with next hop 10.0.0.5

and in router B nothing (since it is directly connected so it knows the network)

If the client's are windows use Pathping IP to see routes and tracert.

Comment: I updated the diagram to include default gateways.

Comment: The troubling behavior that I see is this: a `tracert -d 192.168.3.10` from `station_a` goes out through the Internet interface of `inet_gateway`!

Comment: the issue then is in the router 10.0.0.1. it's not doing the redirection properly and that one is not in the diagram

Comment: Sorry, the updated diagram was still incorrect. 10.0.0.1 is inet_gateway. It's certainly not doing the ICMP redirect.

Comment: [This post](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/help-configuring-ICMP-redirects/td-p/1189478) suggests that one has to manually add static routes on a Ubiquiti EdgeMax in order to have the OS issue ICMP redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I understand `inet_gateway` is a Ubiquiti running EdgeOS.
Can you ensure that the interface is actually configured for ICMP redirects...

...at the EdgeOS level:

```
    admin@router# set firewall send-redirects enable
```

...and at the linux level?

```
    # sysctl –w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
    # sysctl –w net.ipv4.conf.lo.send_redirects = 1
    # sysctl –w net.ipv4.conf.<if>.send_redirects = 1
    # sysctl –w net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
```

where `<if>` is the interface name where you connect to the `main_network`

I used Vyatta in a similar situation, and had to set manually via sysctl for redirects to be sent, regardless of static routes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: )-8   My EdgeRouterLite doesn't support 'set firewall' or `ip redirect'. All the sysconf values are already 1, though.

Comment: More strangely, when I attempt to traceroute 192.168.3.10 from 10.0.0.10, the ICMP responses indicate that 10.0.0.1 is sending the traffic out the 192.168.0.0/24 interface as if it doesn't even know about the static route I added (through the GUI).

Comment: I wonder if your EdgeRouter is your DHCP server. You can take advantage of RFC3442 and have the DHCP server provide a static router to your clients. I did some basic research, and like Vyatta and VyOS, EdgeOS is using dhcpd as DHCP server, so that may be an option.